# Subclipse / Subversive: Any way to filter out files modified locally

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

Is there any way using Subclipse or Subversive to apply some kind of filter on Package Explorer that will hide all files that weren't modified locally?

It would be sometimes very useful when I just want focus on my local changes (for example to revise them). I know that files that were modified locally are marked in Package Explorer (in Subclipse by "star" symbol)  but in big projects with hundred of files it doesn't help that much (it would be much easier and clearer if only modified files would be visible).

Of course packages containing modified files should be visible as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the Synchronize view?  This shows all your changes in a view which makes it easy to work with the items.  You can also create and group items by changeset when using this view.

Using Subclipse, I set the Synchronize view so that all SVN projects in my workspace are synchronized.  I then pin it and set a schedule to refresh every hour.  Local changes refresh immediately, the hourly schedule is for how often to check the repository for incoming changes.

You can out the view in Outgoing mode if you only want to look at your local changes.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. It provides me more or less what I needed.